# Why is my algorithm for Project Euler Problem 12 so slow?

Tags: performance, algorithm, scala

I have created solution for PE P12 in Scala but is very very slow. Can somebody can tell me why? How to optimize this? calculateDevisors() - naive approach and calculateNumberOfDivisors() - divisor function has the same speed :/

```
import annotation.tailrec

def isPrime(number: Int): Boolean = {
  if (number < 2 || (number != 2 && number % 2 == 0) || (number != 3 && number % 3 == 0))
    false
  else {
    val sqrtOfNumber = math.sqrt(number) toInt

    @tailrec def isPrimeInternal(divisor: Int, increment: Int): Boolean = {
      if (divisor > sqrtOfNumber)
        true
      else if (number % divisor == 0)
        false
      else
        isPrimeInternal(divisor + increment, 6 - increment)
    }

    isPrimeInternal(5, 2)
  }
}

def generatePrimeNumbers(count: Int): List[Int] = {
  @tailrec def generatePrimeNumbersInternal(number: Int = 3, index: Int = 0,
                                            primeNumbers: List[Int] = List(2)): List[Int] = {
    if (index == count)
      primeNumbers
    else if (isPrime(number))
      generatePrimeNumbersInternal(number + 2, index + 1, primeNumbers :+ number)
    else
      generatePrimeNumbersInternal(number + 2, index, primeNumbers)
  }

  generatePrimeNumbersInternal();
}

val primes = Stream.cons(2, Stream.from(3, 2) filter {isPrime(_)})

def calculateDivisors(number: Int) = {
  for {
    divisor &lt;- 1 to number
    if (number % divisor == 0)
  } yield divisor
}

@inline def decomposeToPrimeNumbers(number: Int) = {
  val sqrtOfNumber = math.sqrt(number).toInt

  @tailrec def decomposeToPrimeNumbersInternal(number: Int, primeNumberIndex: Int = 0,
                                               factors: List[Int] = List.empty[Int]): List[Int] = {
    val primeNumber = primes(primeNumberIndex)

    if (primeNumberIndex > sqrtOfNumber)
      factors
    else if (number % primeNumber == 0)
      decomposeToPrimeNumbersInternal(number / primeNumber, primeNumberIndex, factors :+ primeNumber)
    else
      decomposeToPrimeNumbersInternal(number, primeNumberIndex + 1, factors)
  }

  decomposeToPrimeNumbersInternal(number) groupBy {n => n} map {case (n: Int, l: List[Int]) => (n, l size)}
}

@inline def calculateNumberOfDivisors(number: Int) = {
  decomposeToPrimeNumbers(number) map {case (primeNumber, exponent) => exponent + 1} product
}

@tailrec def calculate(number: Int = 12300): Int = {
  val triangleNumber = ((number * number) + number) / 2
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val numberOfDivisors = calculateNumberOfDivisors(triangleNumber)
  val elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime

  printf("%d: V: %d D: %d T: %dms\n", number, triangleNumber, numberOfDivisors, elapsedTime)

  if (numberOfDivisors > 500)
    triangleNumber
  else
    calculate(number + 1)
}

println(calculate())
```

Comment: Look up "Sieve of Eratosthenes" for generating primes....

Comment: Now that you know that the problems with this Trial Division Prime Sieve was in your use of Lazy Streams, see [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Scala) for some really high powered Sieve of Eratosthenes techniques that can blast through simple Euler Problem requirements such as this in a few milliseconds.  Building on those techniques, one can sieve all the primes to one billion in a fraction of a second (faster than the Sieve of Atkin even as implemented by Bernstein using hand tuned C) and about four times faster than that using multi processing.

Answer (score 2):

You could first check *what* is slow. Your prime calculation, for instance, is very, very slow. For each number `n`, you try to divide `n` by each each number from 5 to `sqrt(n)`, skipping multiples of 2 and 3. Not only you do not skip numbers you already know are not primes, but even if you fix this, the complexity of this algorithm is [much worse](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3127) than the traditional Sieve of Eratosthenes. See one Scala implementation for the Sieve [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Scala).

That is not to say that the rest of your code isn't suboptimal as well, but I'll leave that for others.

**EDIT**

Indeed, indexed access to `Stream` is terrible. Here's a rewrite that works with `Stream`, instead of converting everything to `Array`. Also, note the remark before the first `if` for a possible bug in your code.

```
  @tailrec def decomposeToPrimeNumbersInternal(number: Int, primes: Stream[Int],
                                               factors: List[Int] = List.empty[Int]): List[Int] = {
    val primeNumber = primes.head

    // Comparing primeNumberIndex with sqrtOfNumber didn't make any sense
    if (primeNumber > sqrtOfNumber) 
      factors
    else if (number % primeNumber == 0)
      decomposeToPrimeNumbersInternal(number / primeNumber, primes, factors :+ primeNumber)
    else
      decomposeToPrimeNumbersInternal(number, primes.tail, factors)
  }
```

Comment: Prime generation isn't problem. Problem was a slow random access to Stream (List too) (in decomposeToPrimeNumbers). toArray + naive generation of prime fixed the probem. Now i can find solution in ~1000ms. Before change it's took a couple of minutes

Comment: @Evil See edit for alternate solution (to creating an `Array`). Plus a possible bug fix. Note, however, that you'll often need to find primes in Euler. A good prime generator is handy.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is clean & fast. I implemented Sieve Of Atking - http://pastebin.com/2q6j3jbL Can You look and check there are no stupid errors like this with prime index?

Comment: @Evil There's a few changes in style I'd make, but I don't see anything wrong. Replacing the for loop with a while loop will make it faster, but this looks plenty fast already.

Comment: @EvilIpos, I know this comment is very old, but you might want to check back to the Wikipedia article for new Sieve of Atkin pseudo code:  The code from which you wrote your program isn't really the SoA because it doesn't limit the range of x and y to only as required; it was also much more inefficient than the real SoA due to over simplifications but these by a constant factor.  Finally, none of these "one big memory array" algorithms, SoE or SoA are very efficient for large ranges due to CPU cache associativity problems and thus slow memory access:  page segmenting is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Slow compared to....?   How do you know it's an issue with Scala, and not with your algorithm?

An admittedly quick read of the code suggests you might be recalculating primes and other values over and over.  `isPrimeInternal` jumps out as a possible case where this might be a problem.

Comment: I never say it is a Scala issue. I know it is a issue of my code. What's wrong with isPrimeInternal?

Comment: Might want to edit the title, then ;)  "Scala: Why it is so slow?..."

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not compilable, some parts are missing, so I'm guessing here. Some thing that frequently hurts performance is boxing/unboxing taking place in collections. Another thing that I noted is that you cunstruct your primes as a Stream - which is a good thing - but don't take advantage of this in your isPrime function, which uses a primitive 2,3-wheel (1 and 5 mod 6) instead. I might be wrong, but try to replace it by

```
def isPrime(number: Int): Boolean = {
  val sq = math.sqrt(number + 0.5).toInt
  ! primes.takeWhile(_ <= sq).exists(p => number % p == 0)
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/768E9fEn here is a compilable source. Stream was a bottleneck. When I replaced to

val primes = generatePrimeNumbers(10000)

it's take 1/10 of orginal time.

Answer (score 0):

My scala algorithm that calculates divisors of a given number. It worked fine in the solution of 
Project Euler Problem 12.

def countDivisors(numberToFindDivisor: BigInt): Int = {

```
def countWithAcc(numberToFindDivisor: BigInt, currentCandidate: Int, currentCountOfDivisors: Int,limit: BigInt): Int = {

  if (currentCandidate >= limit) currentCountOfDivisors

  else {

    if (numberToFindDivisor % currentCandidate == 0)

      countWithAcc(numberToFindDivisor, currentCandidate + 1, currentCountOfDivisors + 2, numberToFindDivisor / currentCandidate)

    else

      countWithAcc(numberToFindDivisor, currentCandidate + 1, currentCountOfDivisors, limit)

  }

}

countWithAcc(numberToFindDivisor, 1, 0, numberToFindDivisor + 1)
```

}

Answer (score -2):

calculateDivisors can be greatly improved by only checking for divisors up to the square root of the number. Each time you find a divisor below the sqrt, you also find one above.

```
def calculateDivisors(n: Int) = {
  var res = 1
  val intSqrt = Math.sqrt(n).toInt
  for (i <- 2 until intSqrt) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
          res += 2
      }
  }
  if (n == intSqrt * intSqrt) {
      res += 1
  }
  res
}
```

Comment: calculateDivisors returns devisors "as is" not the number of devisors, this is a test code

Comment: @Evil Ipos - you can still only go up to the square root. Use the fact that if `x` is a divisor of `n`, then `n / x` is also a divisor of `n`. Watch out for the case when `n` is a perfect square.