# JVM OOM Error - Finding prime numbers using scala stream

Tags: scala, stream, primes

I am using Scala Stream to find out prime numbers between two numbers, but it is throwing `Java OutofMemoryError`. Can someone tell me why is it happening so?

```
def sieve(nums: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  nums.head #:: sieve(nums.tail filter (_ % nums.head != 0))
}  

def listPrimesinRange(start: Int, end: Int): List[Int] = {
  sieve(Stream.from(2)).filter(x => (x >= start && x <= end)).toList
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this scala prime generation so slow/memory intensive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802112/why-is-this-scala-prime-generation-so-slow-memory-intensive)

Comment: see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985539/scala-erastothenes-is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-replace-a-stream-with-an/20991776#comment31606932_20986428).