# Checking whether a number is prime in Scala

Tags: scala

I wanted to check if a number is prime or not. I wrote the following code, but it does not return any value:

```
 def isprime(x:Int) = {
     | if (x==1) false
     | else {
     | for (i <- 2 to x-1) {
     | if (x % i == 0) false
     | else true
     | }
     | }
     | }
```

Comment: where are you running it ? and how are you running it ?

Comment: you can get answer at this link :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711785/find-prime-numbers-using-scala-help-me-to-improve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711785/find-prime-numbers-using-scala-help-me-to-improve)

Comment: I am using the Scala REPL

Comment: @AlirezaIzadimehr I read that link, but I needed to use simple if-else statements to accomplish it

Comment: Check the answer and accept it if it solves your problem !

Comment: I think the answers while not wrong are not really addressing the issue. Amab, the problem is that your for loop isn't resulting in any value - you calculate a true/false value, but then don't do anything with it. So your else clause doesn't result in any value (in fact, it produces `Unit`).  You need to return false as soon as you find a divisor - and the way to do that is probably `exists` as in @eliasah's answer.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I would like to add your comment into my answer, if that's ok with you. At some level, I thought that it was implied but it didn't seem to be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you did is a called defining a function so obviously it won't return anything and as a matter of fact, this function returns AnyVal which obviously won't help you much. I suspect that you actually need a Boolean type returned.

Since you are working with the REPL, you would want to define your function to check if a number is prime. I called it `isPrime2` and then test it.

```
def isPrime2(i :Int) : Boolean = {
|     if (i <= 1)
|       false
|     else if (i == 2)
|       true
|     else
|       !(2 to (i-1)).exists(x => i % x == 0)
|   }
// isPrime2: (i: Int)Boolean

(1 to 10).foreach(i => if (isPrime2(i)) println("%d is prime.".format(i)))
// 2 is prime.
// 3 is prime.
// 5 is prime.
// 7 is prime.
```

I would even suggest a simpler version if you care not using if else conditions :

```
def isPrime1(n: Int): Boolean = ! ((2 until n-1) exists (n % _ == 0))
```

Which also returns a Boolean.

**EDIT:**

As @TheArchetypalPaul stated, which was also implied, the problem is that your for loop isn't resulting in any value - you calculate a true/false value, but then don't do anything with it. So your else clause doesn't result in any value (in fact, it produces `Unit`). You need to return false as soon as you find a divisor - and the way to do that is probably exists as in `isPrime1`.

Comment: A further refinement suitable for large numbers: `def isPrime(n: Long): Boolean = !(2 +: (3 to Math.sqrt(n).toInt by 2) exists (n%_ == 0))`

Comment: As shown in the comment by @jwvh there is no point in checking numbers higher than the square root of `n`. It's also nice that it skips the even numbers: no point in checking them all if you are checking `2` already.

Comment: @jwvh just noticed that your solution will return `true` for `1` as well as some negative numbers. You need an explicit check for that.

Comment: @Sim, correct.  My solution was offered as a performance enhancement to the suggested "simpler version".  The original's edge-case deficiencies were not addressed.

Comment: I don't know about Amab, but for my application I need `isPrime(-47)` (for example) to return true. Of course it would take just a minor adjustment.

Answer (score 8):

One liner Solution

```
def isPrime(num:Int):Boolean =
(num > 1) && !(2 to scala.math.sqrt(num).toInt).exists(x => num % x == 0)
```

Comment: In the second line, I found any number from 1 to num/2, divides the given number. If yes that means it is not prime.
For example, 10 -> It will check 2 to 3 and 2 will divide 10 so this is not prime. 
I just took the negation of the result to the second.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one more 1 line solution:

```
def isPrime(n: Int) = Range(2, n-1).filter(i => n % i == 0).length == 0
```

Or even shorter:

```
def isPrime(n: Int) = Range(2, n-1).filter(n % _ == 0).length == 0
```

Comment: Sure, `def isPrime(n: Int) = Range(2, n-1).exists(n % _ == 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

This one is less elegant than the one liners, but a bit faster. It uses the fact that all primes (except 2 and 3) have to be at `6k±1`. So it skips testing numbers which are dividable by 2 or 3. It will only test for the groups of (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19) and so on.

```scala
def isPrime(number: Int): Boolean =
  if (number < 4) number > 1
  else if (number % 2 == 0 || number % 3 == 0) false
  else (5 to math.sqrt(number).toInt by 6).forall(i => number % i != 0 && number % (i + 2) != 0)
```

Comment: That's very clever. Tysvm for posting. I've just updated my answer to indicate yours is more efficient than mine. I also provided a conversion to `Long` as that is what I needed. And it is easy to trip up converting an `Int` implementation into a `Long` implementation. If you were to also provide a properly implemented `Long` version, I would be happy to remove my conversion and just point to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another one liner:

```
def isPrime(num: Int): Boolean = (2 to num) forall (x => num % x != 0)
```

`forall` will check if the predicate holds for all elements of this range

I just realised that the code above is a bit slow for bigger numbers, so here an improved version:

```
def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = (2 to math.sqrt(n).toInt) forall (x => n % x != 0)
```

Comment: These functions return `true` for 0 and 1 which are not prime numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the solutions in the answers to this question appear to either not work, haven't covered obvious edge cases, and/or are blatantly inefficient.

Below is my answer which works, covers all edge cases, and is as efficient as it is possible to be in this particular domain; i.e. it checks as few values as possible and it fails early as possible if the number isn't a prime.

```
def isPrime(long: Long): Boolean =
  if (long > 8L) {
    !(((long % 2L) == 0L)
      || (3L to math.sqrt(long).toLong by 2L).exists(n => (long % n) == 0L))
  } else
    (long > 1L) && ((long == 2L) || ((long % 2L) != 0L))
```

**UPDATE (2019/09/18):**
I stand corrected about my solution being "is as efficient as it is possible to be in this particular domain". The [solution provided by @kanbagoly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57645847/501113) is actually more efficient in that it has fewer checks. His is implemented using `Int`. Here's his solution reimplemented using `Long` just in case you want to only do a copy/paste and not run into stupid `Int` versus `Long` issues:

```
def isPrime(long: Long): Boolean =
  if (long < 4L)
    long > 1L
  else if (((long % 2L) == 0L) || ((long % 3L) == 0L))
    false
  else
    (5L to math.sqrt(long).toLong by 6L)
      .forall(n => ((long % n) != 0L) && ((long % (n + 2L)) != 0L))
```

Comment: I read somewhere that `(long & 1) == 0` might have an efficiency edge.

Comment: That technique used to be needed, back in the early days of the JVM (prior to 2005). However, both the Java compiler and the HotSpot compiler now have explicit transforms/mappings for all of the basic bit operations, very much like the one you are describing (and many more).

Answer (score 2):

This can be a solutions.

```
def isPrime(integer: Int): Boolean = {
   if (integer == 1) false
   else {
      val domain = (2 to math.sqrt(integer).toInt).view
      val range = domain filter (isDivisibleBy(integer, _))
      range.isEmpty
   }
}

def isDivisibleBy(integer: Int, divisor: Int): Boolean = integer % divisor == 0
```

Now coming back to the code that you have written, your code returns **AnyVal** and desired return type should be **Boolean**. And the reason behind that is in Scala (or any functional language) for loop is an *expression* not a *control structure*.

Answer (score 2):

Comment on the former answers (except @jwvh): there is no need to use even numbers more than once. After a test by 2, the domain `3 to math.sqrt(integer).toInt by 2` must be used.

I have developed an accelerated tail-recursive version. It skips even values, and test two values in one go.

See it for yourself, running in your browser [Scastie (remote JVM)](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Cloudius/SOE6nrfTQ06B0ZYcMdTNNw/6).

```
import java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis

import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet
import scala.io.Source

// Primality by trial division

object PrimesTestery extends App {
  val oeisPrimes = TreeSet(oeisPrimesText.map(_.toInt): _*)

  def oeisPrimesText = rawText.getLines.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).map(_.split(" ")(1)).toList

  def rawText = Source.fromURL("https://oeis.org/A000040/a000040.txt")

  def isPrime(n: Long) = {
    val end = math.sqrt(n.toDouble).toInt

    @tailrec
    def inner(d: Int): Boolean = {
      (d > end) || (n % d != 0 && n % (d + 2) != 0) && inner(d + 6)
    }

    n > 1 && ((n & 1) != 0 || n == 2) && (n % 3 != 0 || n == 3) && inner(5)
  }

  println(s"Found ${oeisPrimes.size} primes on OEIS , last is ${oeisPrimes.last}.")
  for (i <- (0 to oeisPrimes.last))
    assert(isPrime(i.toLong) == oeisPrimes.contains(i), s"Wrong $i")

  println(s"✔ Successfully completed without errors. [total ${currentTimeMillis - executionStart} ms]")

}
```

To be sure, this code test against the known list of primes for primes ánd composite numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
def isPrime(n: Int) = (2 until n) forall(x => n % x !=0)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your post to include an explanation for your code. This will make your answer more useful and more likely to be upvoted

Answer (score 1):

also you can use this recursive function:

```
def isPrime(n: Int):Boolean = {
  def isPrimeUntil(t: Int): Boolean =
    if (t<=1) true
    else n%t != 0 && isPrimeUntil(t-1)

    isPrimeUntil(n/2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That works fine for negative numbers and big numbers too.
Prime numbers start from  2, 3, 5, ...

```
def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = (n > 1) && ! Range(2, n-1).exists(n % _ == 0)
```

Also

```
@tailrec
def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = {
   def isPrimeTailrec(divisor: Int): Boolean = {
     if(divisor > Math.sqrt(Math.abs(n))) true
       else n % divisor != 0 && isPrimeTailrec(divisor + 1)
     }
     if(n < 2) false
     else isPrimeTailrec(2)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Wilson's theorem.
p is prime if (p-1)! = -1 mod p.
Normally computing (p-1)! is expensive as the number becomes huge, but computing the factorial mod p is less than p.

```
def prime(p):Boolean = {
  if (p==1)
    false
  else if (Seq(2,3,5,7,11).contains(p))
    false
  else
    // detect whether (p-1)! == -1 mod p
    (2 until p).fold(1)((acc:Int,i:Int) => (acc * i) % p) == p-1
}
```

Answer (score -2):

def primeNumber(range: Int): Unit ={

```
val primeNumbers: immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] =

  for (number :Int <- 2 to range) yield{

    val isPrime = !Range(2, Math.sqrt(number).toInt).exists(x => number % x == 0)

    if(isPrime)  number
  }

for(prime <- primeNumbers) println(prime)
```

}

Comment: This does not answer the question directly and displays very poor Scala style. Have you read any of the other answers already posted (over a year ago)?

Comment: actually i just started leaning Scala from today and this is the first program that i written so i thought that it might help for beginner. thanks for reply

Comment: When a question is this old, and has many other answers, you should explain why you are posting a new and different answer. In this case your `isPrime` calculation is not significantly different from other posted answers and the rest of your code sets a bad example for beginners.